# Can you install the Xcode 5 Developer Preview in parallel with Xcode 4.6.2?

Tags: xcode, xcode5

Apple announced the Xcode 5 Developer Preview today and I want to try it.

But before I download this, I want to know that what happen with my current version of Xcode (version 4.6.2)?

Will the Xcode 5 Developer Preview install as a different application or it will remove the old version? Will some common tools collide, like the command line tools?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The Xcode 5 developer preview comes as a normal app DMG (not with the usual packager/installer) and has a different name.

So essentially, you download it, open a DMG, then pull to the Applications folder and thence have two Xcodes there (the old and the new one called `Xcode5-DP`).  It even comes with a slightly different icon (red badge across a corner) and the intro screen is different too, so there is very little chance of confusing them.

I already did that today (and a colleague also).

Comment: XC5 does, however, install "additional components". Hopefully without damaging the existing XC4 components...

Comment: It will install the XC5 versions of the command-line tools, like xcodebuild. But you can use `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` to switch back to the old ones.

Comment: Even re-installing command line tools from XCode4 won't help. So thanks for the tip JW!

Comment: But the developer preview seems to change the iPhone Simulator (so that it runs iOS 7) and then XCode 4.6 has trouble communicating with the simulator. Any workarounds?

Nevermind -- seems you just have to make sure to close the simulator in between.

Comment: You can also visually choose which versions of the Command Line Tools to use: open "Preferences > Locations > Locations" and choose Xcode 4.6 or Xcode 5 for the field "Command Line Tools". Screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qVjPe.png

Comment: The GM released yesterday doesn't rename xcode.app. Now it wants to overwrite it. I'm assuming you could drag it somewhere else and rename it before dragging it into applications to avoid it overwriting 4.x.

Answer (score 19):

Now that xcode 5 has reached the first official release and is no longer in beta, you have to do ONE of the following if you wish to keep BOTH versions.

1. Run the dmg of the new version you download from developer.apple.com. Drag the app to applications, and when asked to overwrite click KEEP BOTH. This will rename the existing app to xcode 2 I believe.
2. Select your existing xcode 4 in applications. Rename it to xcode4 or whatever. Now you can drag in the new version without overwriting the existing one.
3. Drag the new xcode to someplace other than applications. Rename it and then drag it into applications.

I personally favour option 2, since going forward we'll be using xcode 5 and it's helpful if it retains the default name from the get go for easy updating.

BTW, if you do have more than one xcode installed expect the mac app store to report that you need to do an update. Probably best to install it by downloading it from the developer portal if this sort of thing bugs you.

Comment: This question is specific for Xcode Developer Preview not for GM version. Someone may down vote your answer for this.

Comment: @CRDAVE Since that version can no longer be downloaded, and this question comes up first when you do a google search, I thought it was important to have the full info on what to do with GM and later versions.

Answer (score 3):

Xcode 5 preview works fine with Xcode 4.6.2 or any other Xcode, It has different icon and it runs from its .dmg file (no install).

Pay attention you cannot submit an app with Xcode 5, So keep the old Xcode till Apple would release the stable version of Xcode 5.

Comment: I downloaded xcode5-DP2.dmg from developer.apple. When I open it, I don't see new icon, I see old one crossed out. What's wrong?

Comment: Open .dmf file and drag the Xcode-DP2 to applications folder. it has a "preview" label...

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Dont replace XCode 4!
If you plan to deploy some app to appstore, you can't do it using Xcode 5 at this moment.

The best way is download the Xcode 5 version, unpack it and run the app on different folder (not application folder). You will stay with Xcode 4, and can run Xcode 5 separated (You don't need to 'install' xcode 5).